# laravel 5.4 change "from address" without changing smtp username

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have set the from address in config/mail.php. but in mail, from address is smtp username. Is that possible to change the from address without changing smtp credentials.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#configuring-the-sender

Comment: I have already make changes according to doc as you send above link. but it take smtp username in from address.

Comment: If you're sending via Gmail, they override the sender. Other major providers probably do similar things.  You can set a `Reply-To` header, or send via a different provider that's intended for this sort of thing - Sendgrid, for example.

Answer (score 1):

.env File

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=HOST_NAME
MAIL_PORT=PORT
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS
MAIL_FROM_NAME=YOUR_NAME
```

config/mail.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

//  'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', null),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', null)
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Just only change in config/mail.php in from array like

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', null),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', null)
],
```

After clear the cache and try:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```